# Нужно ли обособлять "говорим мы о чем-то светлом и добром"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Совсем не важно, говорим мы о чем-то светлом и добром(,) или о злодеянии, от которого волосы встают дыбом.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении лучше использовать повторяющийся союз ЛИ...ИЛИ, в этом случае запятая ставится:

*Совсем не важно, говорим **ли** мы о чем-то светлом и добром,  **или** о злодеянии, от которого волосы встают дыбом.*

Розенталь (пункт 4, примечание):   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

Одиночный союз ИЛИ, объединяющий однородные дополнения, неудобно использовать, так как ко второму однородному члену относится придаточное предложение.

Comment: Спасибо. Но если отсутствует повторяющийся союз, то запятая не нужна?

Comment: Запятая не нужна в таком предложении: Совсем не важно, говорим  мы о чем-то светлом и добром или о  каком-то злодеянии. Эти дополнения являются однородными (запятая не ставится, паузы нет). Но если второе дополнение имеет собственное придаточное, а мы объединим два дополнения союзом ИЛИ, то придаточное будет относиться к ним обоим. Поэтому такая структура будет некорректной.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.